# bash help (ubuntu)

Tags: command-line, upgrade, updates

I made a script that has an update command running first

for example

```
sudo apt -y update
```

I need to make sure that if SYSTEM updates are available , the script will
ask me if i want to update

so

EXCEPTION

the script will check for system updates , if updates are available i will be
asked if i want to update ("Would you like to update? Y/N)

if Y is selected , the script will perform the following command

```
apt -y upgrade
```

I am aware that in production areas you do not perform update and upgrades on the fly , but this is only for my set up.

Is it possible to do so using the command - trap , or read command?

**Edit from comment:**
Okay so here is the script https://github.com/V4riableZ/Tools/tree/master/Bash In the line where i perform apt update , i want to know if updates are available and also , to be asked if i want to perform apt -y upgrade ("System updates are available , would you like to upgrade now? Y/N")

Comment: Why does not `apt upgrade` suffice? Also remember that `apt` is a front end for various other (`apt-get` and `apt-cache` comes to mind) programs, and as such it's maybe better to wrap those directly?

Comment: I did not understand your question

Comment: If you run `apt upgrade` it will ask before performing any changes. Why would this not suffice?

Comment: @vidario is trying to say that if you run: `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`, you will experience the behavior you have described.  If you run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`, you will automatically install updates and it will not ask you for confirmation.  It's unclear what you're asking to fix, or what your ultimate goal is.

Comment: Please provide us about your script to auto-update or auto-uprade of apt?

Comment: Okay so here is the script

Comment: Okay so here is the script

https://github.com/V4riableZ/Tools/blob/master/Bash/quick_vagrant_latest/install_64bit.sh

In the line where i perform apt update , i want to know if updates are available and also , to be asked if i want to perform apt -y upgrade ("System updates are available , would you like to upgrade now? Y/N")